# Build Task to Conditionally Copy Files to a Directory

Tags: tfs, msbuild, azure-pipelines-build-task

I am completely new to vNext Tasks & need some help.  I have some Custom Configuration values defined in my Solutions, as follows:

- DEV
- DEV.HA (HA stands for High Availability)
- QA
- QA.HA
- UAT
- UAT.HA
- PROD
- PROD.HA

I have Service Account certificates in a set of folders separated by-environment.  These need to be copied into a KEYS folder to replace the default files there.

FOR INSTANCE:

- DEV & DEV.HA would get from one source-folder
- QA & QA.HA would get from a different source-folder

...and so on.

- How do you do conditional copying in vNext?
- Which vNext task is best for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either stick the "variable part" in a variable. This would be possible if you have naming logic that allows you to do configuration by convention.

Or put the logic in a powershell script or shell script and run that to set the values of the variables. There are special logging commands you can use to set the value of a variable from your script:

```
write-host ##vso[task.setvariable variable=YourVariableName;]QA
```

Then use the variable either in the standard Copy Files task or stick the copy files logic in Powershell as well.